# Consulta para Linetime en MySQL PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy haciendo una linea de tiempo asi como lo muestro en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, lo de rojo son las fechas y lo de azul son los eventos que pasan en las fechas hasta alli todo bien. Sin embargo, me repite las fechas dejo mis consultas:

```
<div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="active tab-pane" id="mic">
                <?php
                                    $sql_especie=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mic_dta ORDER BY date_micdta DESC LIMIT 5");
                                        while ($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_especie)){
                    $fecha=$rw["date_micdta"];
                ?>
                  <div class='timeline timeline-inverse'>
                    <div class='time-label'>
                      <span class='bg-danger'>
                        <?php echo $fecha ?>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <?php                                  
                        $sql_especie2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mic_dta WHERE date_micdta BETWEEN '".$fecha."' AND '".$fecha."'");
                        $fecha2=$rw["date_micdta"];
                        $fecha3=$rw["nombre_porteador_micdta"];
                        $fecha4=$rw["time_micdta"];
                       
                        while ($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_especie2)){               
                    ?>                             
                    <div>
                      <i class='fas fa-user bg-info'></i>
                        <div class='timeline-item'>
                          <span class='time'><i class='far fa-clock'></i><?php echo $fecha4 ?></span>
                            <h3 class='timeline-header border-0'><?php echo $fecha3 ?></h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                      } 
                    ?>
                                  
                     <?php
                }   
                ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Es necesario mencionar que en la primera consulta la columna date_micdta la estoy almacenando en la variable $fecha que luego uso en la segunda consulta

Comment: Filtra los resultados por fecha, suponiendo que quieres los de hoy _22 de junio de 2020_ el filtro quedaría más o menos: `WHERE campo_fecha BETWEEN '2020-06-22 00:00:00' AND '2020-06-22 23:59:59'`

Comment: Triby gracias por responder, ese filtro lo aplico en la consulta para sacar las fechar que estan en rojo o los eventos que estan en azul?

Comment: Para los que están en azul: Fecha seleccionada, desde las 00:00:00 hasta las 23:00:00 horas

Comment: Triby segui tu consejo y me funcionooo!! Gracias peeeeeeero ahora tengo otro problemita, da la casualidad que ahora se repiten los que estan en rojo te envio la imagen https://prnt.sc/t4moew

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código con el que ejecutas las consultas. No asumas que nosotros sabemos qué y cómo lo haces.

Comment: Lo siento, ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: _Es necesario mencionar que ..._ no es muy útil mencionar así nada mas, sirve más el código para saber si estás usando un ciclo, dos o los que sean, para tratar de averiguar porqué se repiten.

Comment: Triby, vuelvo a disculparme ya edite mi post nuevamente

Comment: Triby estube empapandome un poco de mysql y a la consulta de arriba de agregue el GROUP BY y ya me quedo perfecto!! Gracias!!